# Stop Simulink using From block

Tags: if-statement, simulink

I have made a short simulation to display a ballistic trajectory.

I had like to set a condition that if `altitude <= zero` and  `time > 1` second, to stop the simulation.

I initialized the simulation to be for example 100 seconds but I expect it to stop when needed.

I tried the following:

[image]

However im getting an error saying:

```
Port 1 of
'Simulation/If'
can only be
connected to an
action subsystem
and may not be
connected to more
than one action
subsystem
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `If-Else` blocks for this.  You should be using [Compare to Constant](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/comparetoconstant.html) blocks.

The output of the `If` block is designed to be used as an enable signal for an `Action` subsystem, which is what the error is trying to tell you.